# Is an Artinian ring also a division ring?

Tags: ring-theory

If i have an Artinian ring with $xy \neq 0, \ \ \forall x,y \neq 0$ is there any chance to have and a division ring ? Any reference would be helpful.

Comment: what do you mean? aren't fields clearly both artinian and division rings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Artinian integral domains are fields. To see this, let $A$ be an Artinian ring and $x \in A \setminus \{0\}$. Then consider the chain

$$ xA \supseteq x^2A \supseteq x^3A \supseteq \cdots $$

Since $A$ is Artinian, we must have $x^nA = x^{n + 1}A$ for some $n$. Thus $x^n = x^{n + 1}y$ for some $y \in A$ and since $A$ is a domain, we can cancel to get $1 = xy$. Thus $A$ is a field.

Comment: Clearly from this proof, rings with DCC on such chains of ideals (a broader class than Artinian rings) which are domains are also division rings. Another way to approach it is that a domain with a minimal right ideal is a division ring (same idea: if $xA=x^2A$, you have $x=x^2a$, either $x$ is zero or it cancels and is a unit.) Of course, Artinian rings have minimal right ideals...

Comment: @rschwieb Interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An integral domain is an Artinian ring if and only if it is a field.

Check out this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artinian_ring)

Answer (score 0):

1. A left Artinian ring is left Noetherian as a consequence of [Hopkins-Levitsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopkins%E2%80%93Levitzki_theorem).
2. A left Noetherian domain satisfies Ore's condition and it is thus a left Ore domain.
3. Left Ore domains can be embedded in a division ring, by Ore's theorem.

All in all, a left Artinian ring can be embedded in a division ring.
No commutativity required.